# If maxSizeRollBackups is decreased in Log4Net config, it is not deleting extra log files

Tags: c#, log4net

When `maxSizeRollBackups` is decreased (suppose 4 to 2), it is expected that, only 2 files should be kept and extra files should be deleted, but it is not happening.
However, In case I increase the `maxSizeRollBackups` value, it is working according to the count.

Log4Net setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<log4net>
<logger name="ConsoleLog">
  <level value="FATAL" />
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <level value="WARN" />
  <level value="INFO" />
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleLogFile" />
</logger>
<appender name="ConsoleLogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{ConsoleSetup}" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="4" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1KB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <Encoding value="UTF-8" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <!-- %d:DateTime, %t:Thread, %-5p:Categories, %c:LoggerName, %m:ADKMessage, %n:line sepalator-->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d ,%-5p, %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Watcher in C# on the log config:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(sPath));
```

According to `maxSizeRollBackups` setting (4) above, below files are existing.

> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log"
>
> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log.1"
>
> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log.2"
>
> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log.3"
>
> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log.4"

Then I set, `maxSizeRollBackups` to 2 then I think, below files should be deleted, but not getting deleted. **I want to find out cause of this issue**

> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log.3"
>
> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log.4"

Note, If I set, `maxSizeRollBackups` to 6 then files below are getting generated as expected.

> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log.5"
>
> "Application_ConsoleSetup.log.6"

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work like that - the rule will be applied to new logs, therefore the reduced count is only touching the first 2 files.

Comment: @Oliver Thank you for your comment.You might be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is that `Log4net` doesn't do a full inventory of its log files and deletes those that shouldn't be there according to the current configuration. It just observes the configuration settings while it is logging. Looking at the method `RollOverRenameFiles` in RollingFileAppender.cs, you can see that if a log file rollover happens, the oldest file is being deleted and the other files are renamed. "Oldest file" refers to the oldest file according to the *current* configuration. If your configuration states that there should only be 2 backups, the oldest file is `<baseFilename>.2`. `Log4net` never checks if there are other files (`.3`, `.4` and so on) that were created earlier due to a different configuration.